# Firefox 4.0.1 ignore expires HTTP header

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, browser

In my opinion,when I browse from page A to page B,if B page have same js/css/img/etc resources in the A page, browser should use the cache from A page due to it's in the same session,so this will end up a 304 request(if resouces have exprie time set it will not request).

However, I come across a question today.

In Firefox, when I browser Page A,the waterfall in firebug is

[image: waterfall of Page A]

But when I click a link to go to Page B,the waterfall in firebug is

[image]

The js/css is still download from the server,not a 302 request.

My Firefox version is 4.0.1 and cache is not disable.

Is this behavior correct in Firefox?

Comment: Not really a question for SO imo. Either way, it depends on both your client settings and the server's settings (server can state how a file should be cached). Furthermore, why are you using Firefox 4.0.1?

Comment: @Kippie Our Client Application is based on this version and can't change.I download a new version and try

Comment: @Kippie I check it in Firefox 24 and all the resouces is in BFCache and that fits my opinion.However in old version of Firefox that's so weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean a `304 Not Modified` response.

You only get that response on a conditional request, which will only be issued by the browser if the previous request to the same URI was responded to with the appropriate caching headers.

See for example [HTTP Caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching), [A Beginner's Guide to HTTP Cache Headers](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/), and so on.

Comment: thx, I mean 304 and typed error- -

Answer (score 1):

I figure out this problem by adding a cache-control header.
Thx for @CodeCaster 's advice.

In my situation,all the js/css is downloaded from Apache.I had set expires header for these static content.

However,this old version Firefox seems to trigger a weird request ignore the expires tag.